# Any way to re-show Game Center login view? (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

My app attempts to log the player in when it finishes loading, like good little apps should (so says Apple). But if the player chooses to cancel the initial log-in, I wanted the app to re-attempt to authenticate the player if the player taps the leaderboard button in the game. (otherwise, of course, the button couldn't do anything if the player is not authenticated)

Unfortunately, after some research I discovered that Apple does not seem to allow an app try again to re-authenticate the player after the player cancels the first time, until the player exits and re-enters the game. (If the player cancels three or so times, Apple goes aggro and disables Game Center from the app on that device entirely. Even logging into Game Center from the stand alone app won't help after that point.)

Is there any way around this so that my app can attempt the authentication both when the app loads, and any time the player taps leaderboard button while not logged in? Or do I just have to have my leaderboard button display a message when not authenticated saying that Apple's being dumb and overprotective and not letting my app respond the way it should? (Perhaps not quite in those words...)

Comment: I am very interested in this also. apparently setting the `authenticateHandler` property multiple times does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I've used an alternative approach that might solve your requirement. When they tap on the leaderboard, check the Game Center connection state.

If it is not `GCPConnectionStateEnabledFully` then throw up an alert like this "Error connecting to Game Center. Please make sure you are signed into Game Center and check your internet connection". Then inevitably they will leave your app to check and when they return the Login prompt will appear a few seconds after they return to the app.

*Testing note: When you are testing these scenarios you might cancel the login prompt 3 times. If you do that it will stop prompting you altogether and you need to reset all settings in the Settings app. I remember this being really frustrating.*